# Dired: How copy to kill-ring name of parent directory without moving to parent's directory name?

Tags: dired

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Dired

If I want to copy to parent's directory name to kill-ring I go to folder name and press `w`

Here result:

[image: Success copy]

OK. It's work.

But I wan't to move cursor and get parent's directory name.
I try by command `digit-argument w` but I get the next result:

[image: Not get name]

As you can see Emacs copy to kill-ring files name and dirs names. But it not copy the parent's directory name.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Are you asking for a command that moves the cursor temporarily to the top line (where the current directory name is) and then does what `w` does? Can you get what you want by defining and using a keyboard macro? If so, then a recipe that details defining the macro you use would make clear just what action you want to perform. To me it's not clear yet.

Comment: I want the next: it does not matter where is cursor is position on the Dired buffer, I want to get parent name by one command. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's still not very clear what you're asking, but I'm guessing this is it:

```
(defun copy-parent-dir-as-kill ()
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (kill-new (expand-file-name default-directory)))
```

If you don't want to convert `~/` to its expansion, remove the `expand-file-name`.

(This is unrelated to Dired+ or even to Dired in general, BTW.  You can use the same command in any buffer, to copy the current directory to the `kill-ring`.)